# F# Riddle: how to call an overload of a method?

Tags: c#, interop, f#, methods, call

### First part: call F# from F#

Let's say we have the following type defined in F#:

```
type MyClass =
    static member Overload1 (x, y) = "Pim"
    static member Overload1 (x : System.Tuple<_, _>) = "Pam"
    static member Overload1 x = "Pum"
```

You are now in another module (in another file).

How can you call each of the three methods shown above?

### Second part: call C# from F#

Now, you define a class in C#:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static string Overload1<a, b>(a x, b y) { return "Pim"; }
    public static string Overload1<a, b>(Tuple<a, b> x) { return "Pam"; }
    public static string Overload1<a>(a x) { return "Pum"; }
}
```

From a F# code, how can you call each of the three methods now defined in C#?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the edit, Brian. I think I'm starting to get **too** used to type inference!

Comment: What is interesting here is that both the F# and C# compilers will generate the same method signature for the "Pam" methods, however you need to use different (and hackish) syntaxes to call them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer to the F# part:

```
MyClass.Overload1(1,2)
MyClass.Overload1<_,_>(unbox (box (1,2)) : System.Tuple<int,int>)
MyClass.Overload1 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, I am unclear if it is possible to call the F# "Pam" method.  But here's the rest.

C#:

```
using System;
namespace CSharp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static string Overload1<a, b>(a x, b y) { return "Pim"; }
        public static string Overload1<a, b>(Tuple<a, b> x) { return "Pam"; }
        public static string Overload1<a>(a x) { return "Pum"; }
    }
}
```

F#:

```
namespace FSharp

type MyClass =
    static member Overload1 (x, y) = "Pim"
    static member Overload1 (x : System.Tuple<_, _>) = "Pam"
    static member Overload1 x = "Pum"

namespace DoIt

module Examples =
    let CallFSharp() =
        printfn "%s" <| FSharp.MyClass.Overload1(1,2)   // Pim
        printfn "%s" <| FSharp.MyClass.Overload1((1,2)) // Pum!
        printfn "%s" <| FSharp.MyClass.Overload1(())    // Pum


    let CallCSharp() =
        printfn "%s" <| CSharp.MyClass.Overload1(1,2)             // Pim
        printfn "%s" <| CSharp.MyClass.Overload1<int,int>((1,2))  // Pam
        printfn "%s" <| CSharp.MyClass.Overload1(())              // Pum

    do
        CallFSharp()        
        CallCSharp()
```

Of course, in practice it will be rare to see methods in IL that take `System.Tuple<...>` objects as parameters.